# Mapping many-to-many foreign keys without navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Is it possible to map a list of foreign keys instead of a navigation property using EF 5.0 Code First?

Imagine that I have a Car entity and a Driver entity. A driver can drive multiple cars and a car can have multiple drivers. This is modeled in the database using a join table for the relationship between the Car and Driver tables: `Car_drivers (car_id, driver_id)`

I would like to be able to map this to the following two classes:

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public IList<int> Drives  { get; set; } // List of car ID's
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public IList<int> DrivenBy { get; set; } // List of driver ID's
}
```

How do I map the foreign keys in my database model to this model using EF 5.0 Code First?

### Updated:

Does anyone know if it's supported in NHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Entity Framework can map only collections of related entities. So you should use collection of entities instead of collection of keys:

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Drives  { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Driver> DrivenBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @TommyJakobsen sorry, can't say anything about NHibernate (I think you should create another question for that), but in EF you even can't map simple list of integers, because it works only with entities. You should create some dummy entity which holds integer value and key.